# How to update equations for an ODE in a while loop

Tags: python, ode, runge-kutta

Having trouble outputting the correct values for the 3rd order Runge function. It needs to return the solution at time = t0 + h = 300. I don't think my function is iterating correctly.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: I've tried changing T0 to be just equal to 300 (the initial condition for temperature) and then also changing T0 to be an array of 300 [Ta, Tb]. I've also tried not using a while loop and just having an update equation since its only 1 step and returning that. For context Ta is the temperature of a solar array and Tb is the temperature of a body

Comment: Please add your current code to the question to make support easier!

Comment: The ODE problem and the numerical method should be clearly separated. It should not matter what (not too stiff) ODE is solved with the numerical method, and it should not matter (except in accuracy) what numerical method is applied to a specific ODE. Such a separation allows to apply simple test problems to validate the numerical method and to estimate the quality of the solution by comparing several numerical methods for the same ODE.